# Why do I have potentially leak in CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

My code is:

```
NSString *buffer = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)name, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

NSString *totalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"buffer/%@", buffer];
```

I ran "build and analize tool" and saw : " Object allocated on line 979 and stored into 'buffer' is no longer referenced after this point and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)".

Why do I potentially have a leak in `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the "Create Rule":

> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a
> returned object:
>
> - Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
> - Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name.
>
> If you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish ownership (using CFRelease) when you have finished with it.

Answer (score 5):

Under ARC you should transfer memory management of the returned value using __bridge_transfer:

```
    NSString *buffer = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)name, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [`this`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029), you will see that you are allocating as the method has `Create` in it but not relinquishing the ownership of the string.

Release what you own and you own `buffer`. Add,

```
[buffer release];
```

after you get `totalString`.

Answer (score 0):

What can happen is the analyzer gives you an error on a line, in your case 979, but the object its referring to is actually above it

Without seeing your code I can't be sure but read up a few lines and might see where the error is actually coming from and XCode is only seeing the leak where it's being used

Answer (score 0):

CFURLCreateStringByddingPercentEscapes creates a string with ref count of +1 so you need to release buffer (or autorelease) in order to not leak it..